# ambiguous multiple citations with same authors (first name either full or initials)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Here is minimal example (edited after [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98877/61047))--

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,natbib,
uniquename=false,
uniquelist=minyear,
backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{one,
        author = "Last, F.",
        title = {Title},
        journal = {A Journal},
        year = {2011},
    }
    @article{two,
        author = "Last, F.",
        title = {Title2},
        journal = {B Journal},
        year = {2011},
    } 
    @article{three,
        author = "Last, First",
        title = {Title3},
        journal = {C Journal},
        year = {2013},
    } 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


    \cite{one,two,three}


    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Here is the result --

> Last, 2013; Last 2011a,b

However, I would like to have it something like --

> Last, 2011a,b, 2013

Which I could get if I have all author names identical (including first and last names). I can't really modify the bib entry as long as it is the last option.

Seeing `authoryear-comp` will also set

```
autocite=inline, labeldate=true, uniquename=full, uniquelist=true
```

So, I have already tried different settings using `uniquename` and `uniquelist` of biblatex package ([documentation](http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)), but could not get the desired result. There are some examples given in sec. 4.11.4 of the documentation but it is becoming more ambiguous to me.  Can someone give me correct settings and make it little bit **Disambiguious**?

Comment: Are these all really Mr/Ms First Last?  If so, try adding `sortname = {Last, First},`.  This should produce your desired output. But I cannot imagine how or why BibTeX should produce `Last, 2013; Last, 2011a,b, 2012` given the intput you have. There is no reason to treat author "Last" the same as author "First Last" ... and, more importantly, (in English at least) doing so seems to add to the confusion of an already confusing set of references.  My advice: if they are all the same person, fix your `.bib` entries; if they aren't all the same person, do not let BibTeX treat them as the same.

Comment: Do you mean to use `sortname=...` in each bib item. If so, I can't really do that, I have a big database and I can't change the each entry. But, you point is valid about **Last**. My main argument is between **Last First** and **Last F.** so I have modified the example.

Comment: oh yeah, a typo, thanks. But this does not fix the problem.

Comment: Can you use Biber instead of BibTeX? With Biber the whole name disambiguation feature is greatly improved. BibTeX has the status of "legacy backend" with limited support for the cool features.

Comment: Re the typo: Of course not, but I just wanted to be sure I got the problem.

Comment: @moewe I appreciate your concern. I never used biber but I tried it now, outcome is still the same. If somehow someone can fix this using bibtex, it would be amazing.

Comment: I understand the technical concern you have about the output, but I don't really agree that you couldn't fix the `.bib` file by either 'fixing' the actual `author = ` lines or adding `sortname = `.  Any reasonably editor should make this snap, and regexp could certainly do it with little difficulty. (With Biber you could even do it 'on-the-fly', but not with any less difficulty than simply doing it to fix the `.bib` file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for `biblatex` `Last, F.` and `Last, First` are two different people. It cannot know that they are the same person (if they are at all). So for the most part it will try to treat them separately.

If you load `authoryear-comp` without modifications to the `uniquename`/`uniquelist` options

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

you get

> F. Last 2011a,b; First Last 2013

That is, `biblatex` tries to disambiguate between the two in the citation output.

In your MWE you have `uniquename=false`, and with

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,uniquename=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

you don't get the disambiguation output in the citations. For all other purposes, however, the two authors are still different, though. So the two citations are not compressed.

You can add a `shortauthor` field to the entries

```
@article{one,
  author = "Last, F.",
  shortauthor = {Last, First},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {2011},
}
@article{two,
  author = "Last, F.",
  shortauthor = {Last, First},
  title = {Title2},
  journal = {B Journal},
  year = {2011},
} 
@article{three,
  author = "Last, First",
  shortauthor = {Last, First},
  title = {Title3},
  journal = {C Journal},
  year = {2013},
}
```

Then the citation will be compressed as you expected, because for `biblatex` the author is the same in all works (at least in citations).

(The same should more or less hold for BibTeX as well, though some of its functionality is limited.)

Comment: ok, that means, I can't really force `bibtex` to assume **Last, F.** and **Last, First** same without using `sortauthor` in bib entries. At least, answer clarified my doubts thus accepted.

Comment: A common way of approaching this with `biber` is to use a sourcemap to normalise the name variants before `biblatex` even sees them - there are some examples in the `biblatex` manual.