# Special characters in bib entries using biber/biblatex

Tags: symbols, urls, biber

I'm having problems to get URLs with special characters in `biber`/`biblatex` to work

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}          
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}      

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

This `bib` entry for example. `biber` cannot run with the URL, but if I take it away it works fine. I have other URLs set up in the same way and the work just fine, because there aren't any special characters in them.

```
@ONLINE{biodieselboard,
howpublished = "European Biodiesel Board",
title = " Statistics",
note = "Hämtad: 30/05/2012", 
year = "2012"
url = "http://www.ebb-eu.org/stats.php#",
}
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Don't you need a comma before the URL field?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Error with percent sign in `.bib` entry field when using `biblatex`/`biber`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22179/5764)

Answer (score 6):

If the bib entry is correctly input, there's no problem in compiling it:

```
@ONLINE{biodieselboard,
howpublished = "European Biodiesel Board",
title = " Statistics",
note = "Hämtad: 30/05/2012", 
year = "2012",
url = "http://www.ebb-eu.org/stats.php#",
}
```

Notice the comma that was missing after the `year` field.

[image]