# biblatex with APA problem

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber, texstudio, apa-style

Hi I basically want to use `biblatex` instead of `apacite`. When I try run the following code, it just doesn't run:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myref.bib}
@ARTICLE{ref1,
   author    = "A. E. Gill",
   title     = "Some Simple Solutions for Heat-Induced Tropical Circulation",
   journal   = "Quart. J. R. Met. Soc.",
   volume    = 106,
   year      = 1980,
   pages     = "447-462",
}
@BOOK{TeX,
   author    = "D. E. Knuth",
   title     = "The \tex/book",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year      = 1984,
   note      = "Describes \tex/ in detail",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[american]{babel}
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\bibliography{myref}

\title{Example Title}
\author{Author Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
First line. 

Reference is \textcite{ref1} and \cite{TeX}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I delete `backend=bibtex`, it gives an output but instead of `"Reference is Gill (1980) ..."` it writes: `"Reference is ref1 ..."`. What can be possibly wrong here?

UPDATE:
After fiddling around, I discovered that (with the help of comments of course) the problem is with my system and I guess biber is still buggy.  Here is what I did to solve my problem:

1. Previously I had Miktex 2.9 64 bit version. It turns out that biber is not included in that version ([Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/install-biber-in-miktex-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows)). I reinstall Miktex 32 bit version and it worked.
2. I had to change default bibliography engine in TexStudio from `bibtex` to `biber`.
3. Also, running TexStudio in administrator mode helped. [Check here](http://texstudio.de/?cat=8).
4. `biber` has problems with special characters, i.e. `%` sign ([Check here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22179/error-with-percent-sign-in-bib-entry-field-when-using-biblatex-biber)). It is buggy even though they claim to solve it ([Check here](http://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex-biber/bugs/91/)). Check the URL's and abstracts whether there is a special character. Delete them (what a bummer)..

Comment: Because you have to use `biber` instead of `bibtex` to compile the references.

Comment: As Guide has pointed out, you will have to use Biber. Although in general it is not necessarily required to use Biber, `biblatex-apa` requires Biber. So you cannot use `backend=bibtex`, you have to specify `backend=biber` (or delete the `backend` option altogether, then `backend=biber` will be assumed) and run Biber. Maybe [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) and [How to use biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26516/35864) can help you.

Comment: @Guido @moewe, Thanks for explanations. I believe there is something wrong with the compiler I use `TexStudio`. Because, even though I used the same code as the first comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber), I failed. Also, I tried to add `backend=biber` to the same code I wrote above with a `biber` library I downloaded from [here](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib). Failed again. Anyway thanks for help..

Comment: I almost confirm that there is something wrong with my system. I run the following [code](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/536021c795097ef638269fe3?r=890b7a0e&rs=ps&rm=d) in my computer. No luck. I run this in both TexStudio and in Rstudio. Both did not produce anything like the one on ShareLatex. No References section and instead of regular citations there were the nicknames.

Comment: If the editor seems to have problems, it is a good idea to see if you make things work from the command line.

Comment: @jon, thanks for suggestion. I run from the command line (from command prompt in Windows: `pdflatex trial.tex`). Same thing. There might be a problem with my Miktex 2.9. But `apacite` worked fine.

Comment: Run `pdflatex trial.tex`, `biber trial.bcf`, `pdflatex trial.tex` (this is the normal LaTeX+biber sequence). If you still have problems, make sure your versions of `biber` and `biblatex` match by adding a `\listfiles` in your preamble, running `pdflatex` again, and then checking the version of biblatex you get at the end of your `.log` file against the version of biber (not sure how on windows, but maybe `biber -v`..?).  The `biblatex` manual will tell you which version of `biber` it needs in order to run properly.  And before you do any of that, maybe try to update your installation.

Comment: @jon, previously I had Miktex 2.9 64 bit version. It turns out that `biber` is not included in that version([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/install-biber-in-miktex-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows)). I reinstall Miktex 32 bit version and it worked. Also I need to mention that I had to change default bibliography engine in TexStudio from bibtex to biber.. Thanks for advice..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was solve by reinstalling a TeX distribution

Comment: The URL field is treated as a verbatim field, as such no problems should arise even if you use special characters such as the `%` sign. In other fields - such as the `abstract` field - special characters do have to be escaped - just like normal text in LaTeX. Note that the bug report above says you can ignore the `abstract` field (and other fields), so that a faulty entry does not cause problems - this is not done automatically and not an option if you need the information stored in the `abstract` field.

Comment: `\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype=bibtex]{\map[overwrite]{\step[fieldset=abstract, null]}}}` clears the `abstract` field and thus ignores any faulty entries therein with Biber.