# Problem File ended while scanning use of \field. \begin{document} when compile

Tags: biblatex, errors, compiling, biber

**EDIT 1:** [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6XiD7MJaw4mWXJBSDUxMGtfc2c?usp=sharing) is the full code, including `.tex` and `.bib` files. Any help?

I'm trying to write an article, but all day I've been compiling and always everything goes wrong. I wrote a little code for the example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=authoryear,        
giveninits=true,            
maxcitenames=2,             
uniquelist=false,           
sorting=ynt,                
sortcites,                  
maxbibnames=99, 
url=false,
eprint=false,
dashed=false,               
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\begin{document} 
\section{Introdução}
\parencite{Paerl2009}
\parencite{Pantelic2013}
\end{document}
```

The references are stored in the `References.bib`

```
@Article{Paerl2009,
  author   = {Paerl, H. W. and Huisman, J.},
  title    = {Climate change: a catalyst for global expansion of harmful cyanobacterial blooms},
  journal  = {Environmental Microbiology Reports},
  year     = {2009},
}

@Article{Pantelic2013,
  author   = {Pantelic, D. and Svircev, Z. and Simeunovic, J. and Vidovic, M. and Trajkovic, I.},
  title    = {Cyanotoxins: characteristics, production and degradation routes in drinking water treatment with reference to the situation in {Serbia}},
  journal  = {Chemosphere},
  year     = {2013},
}
```

Always when I compile, I get

> File ended while scanning use of `\field. \begin{document}`

Any hint whats going on?

Comment: Does *exactly that code* give you that error? What is the full text of the error message? Paste the code into a clean `.tex` file. Does it still give you the same error?

Comment: Off-topic: it makes no sense to use author-year and then specify `ynt` sort order. Unless the purpose is to deliberately confound your readers.

Comment: I tested the supplied MWE and I get no error here, except for a warning of conflicting options in `biblatex`. So I reiterate cfr's question.

Comment: @cfr I'm editing the post for you see the full code. It's a little bil longer

Comment: @gusbrs I'm editing the post for you see the full code. It's a little bil longer

Comment: What you need to do is change your example so that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: @cfr I posted an edit. There is all the files for to reproduce the error. See the top od the question

Comment: Please always include the code directly in your question. Do not upload your files to another website and link them here. Some users are wary of random files off the web and won't download them. Simply uploading your files also does not encourage you to make your example minimal. Please try to trim down the code to only what is needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: You have a lot of reserved chars in your `.bib` file, for example the key `Kurniawati2014` has  `...separation efficiency of >93% microalgae cells was found at 20 mg/L of saponin. Removal efficiency of >54.4% and >73.0%...` all these `%` should become `\%`.  If you look carefully at the log, you'll find them.

Comment: Your file has some other problems, but your biggest problem right now are the `%` in the `abstract` field. See [Prevent biber from choking on “%” characters in abstract?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352662/35864), [Error with percent sign in bib entry field when using biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22179/35864)

Comment: Off-topic: load `hyperref` after `biblatex`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/101651.