# Runaway Argument Error

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, arguments

I got this error. Can someone please help me how to resolve this error?

```
{This paper presents the hardened properties of a high-performance fi\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \field.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.86 \begin{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

In addition to that, also i got this error,

> You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Without any [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389), we cannot guess what happened exactly. That being said, the error message is quite explicit: you have a brace somewhere that is never closed, i.e., you have a `{` somewhere and no `}` to close it, and `LaTeX` doesn't like that.

Comment: The second error is also quite explicit: you have, somewhere in your code, a `\cite{key}` where `key` is never defined in your `.bib` file.

Comment: Assuming that you are using biblatex: check if in you bib you have a % in a field (eg in the abstract) and replace that by \%.

Comment: you will probably need to delete your .aux file, which is where the error is, I suspect although you have not shown enough of the message to be sure

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my guess would be the bbl file (which is read at begin document too with biblatex).

Comment: What's the purpose of the "{" character at the start of the string "{This paper presents the hardened properties of..."?

Comment: Part of an abstract in the `bbl`, maybe?

Comment: All singns point at the problem here being a percent sign (%) in one of the `abstract` fields of your `.bib` file. Usually it's better not to export the `abstract` at all, as it probably won't be used. But you can also delete it on the fly before LaTeX gets to see the `%` and chokes on it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22179/35864.